# How can I create a mirror with Unity?

Tags: unity, graphics

Can anyone explain how I can create a mirror effect like the one in [this YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JTxULkb4xMY&playnext=1&list=PLiZAW2FUE1Da5UC4sHwl05uiurncQwaTU&feature=results_main) using Unity Pro?

I know that I need to use render textures to do it, but I am not sure how.

Comment: I've edited your question, if you cannot walk through it-- then it's not really a portal.

Comment: I cant quite recall, but I believe you create a camera facing out from your mirror and then use what the camera "sees" as a render texture on the mirror

Answer (score 2):

Those are done with [Render textures](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/class-RenderTexture.html) . Simply create a new `Render Texture` to your project and a camera to your scene. Then assign that camera's `Target Texture` to the `Render Texture` you created.